# Can I use Google Translate to make my Raspberry Pi speak in different languages on demand?

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, google-translate, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi B+ running the latest Raspbian headless, and have forced output to my 3.5mm audio jack so I can connect speakers and have it "speak" on demand (remotely via SSH would be fantastic).

Google translate has a service call that will read text to you in many languages.  Anyone have any idea how I could use this to make my Raspberry Pi multilingual on demand?

Even just how to make Google Translate speak some given words in English from a command line would be fantastic.  Preferably using a bash script.

Comment: It sounds like you want us to write a script for you. That's not really within the domain of this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found some information that I think will do what you are looking for. I have tried and had success with the following here. Please try it and see what you think.

If you want your Raspberry Pi to be able to speak to you, in 
multiple languages, do the following.

1. In a terminal window type the following (each on a separate line)

> sudo apt-get install alsa-utils
>
> sudo apt-get install mplayer

2. Then lets look at the modules by typing this in a terminal

> sudo nano /etc/modules

3. After typing the above command check the file that opens to see if it shows the following:

> snd_bcm2835

4. if it does exit. If it DOES NOT add it.
5. Then add a line to the mlayer configuration by typing this in a terminal:

> sudo nano /etc/mplayer/mplayer.conf

6. Add the following.
   If you aren't sure where to put it, the bottom works fine

> nolirc=yes

*Be sure to save your changes. It should be CTRL+X to exit and will prompt you to save your changes in nano

---

### Then for the test do the following

> nano speech.sh

Then put the following in a new file called speech.sh and save it.

```
#!/bin/bash
say() { local IFS=+;/usr/bin/mplayer -ao alsa -really-quiet -noconsolecontrols "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=$*"; }
say $*
```

- Helpful tip, be sure to remember to change the permissions to read from the file
  chmod u+x speech.sh

T7. hen type the following as an example to hear audio on your pi.

> ./speech.sh Look Dave I can see youre really upset about this

Comment: This works great!  Took a minute or two for my Pi to install the things, then the command you gave made my Pi speak to me.  Thank you!  Accepting answer...